# Order of execution of message callback function in Visual C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, message-queue

I am in the process of developing a Windows Visual C++ application which will monitor the message pump for various events.  Here is a skeleton of my main cpp file:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;

    // register WindowProcedure() as message callback function
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    // assign other properties...

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    // create main window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx ( ... );

    // infinite message loop
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a skeleton of the callback function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(message) {
        case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
            // handle the update here
    }
}
```

My simple question is whether callback functions are guaranteed to start and end in *sequence*, or is it possible that they might execute in *parallel* with some overlapping?  In other words, is it possible that 2 calls to the callback function could be executing in parallel, possibly leading to a race condition?  Or does Windows guarantee that each message is handled in serial, one at a time?  Any documentation or references you might provide would be welcome.

Comment: Not really related to your question, but you should return messages.wParam from WinMain, rather than 0. When you call PostQuitMessage(0) when handling for example WM_DESTROY, that "0" (the argument to PostQuitMessage) will be the value of messages.wParam after the GetMessage-loop has exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window messages are stored in a queue. Everytime you call GetMessage, it removes the first message from the queue. Your window procedure is called when you call DispatchMessage.

So yes, messages are handled in sequence. However, there is some overlapping possible if inside your window procedure you call SendMessage, as that function bypasses the message queue and just calls your window procedure directly (as opposed to PostMessage which just puts the message in the queue).

But that doesn't mean the window procedure will execute in parallel (as in, from multiple threads). Neither DispatchMessage nor SendMessage will create a different thread to run the window procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  So in other words, assuming I don't call `SendMessage()` from my callback, then a given call to callback function is guaranteed to finish completely before a new call (presumably from another Windows message) begins?

Comment: Yes, SendMessage or anything else that causes the window procedure to be called (e.g. UpdateWindow). But calling SendMessage or something like it from the window procedure is not necessarily a bad thing. For example, it is sometimes useful to re-draw something everytime the window is resized, by calling UpdateWindow.

Comment: The reason I ask this is that I am using multithreading and I need to know which message is currently being handled. Thankfully, it appears that C++ processes message in order.

Comment: If you call SendMessage from a thread which did not create the window handle the program switches to the thread which created the window and handles the message in the window procedure callback function. The calling thread waits until the call is complete. If you call PostMessage from a thread it places a message on the window's message queue (it does not wait). Regardless, the window procedure is executed on the thread which created the window.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: To answer your first question: Correct, but incomplete. You may not be calling `SendMessage` directly, but a Windows API you invoke does. Also worth reading: [When can a thread receive window messages?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/08/150929.aspx) This article illustrates another route to reentrancy. @jensa: `SendMessage` will not switch to another thread. The calling thread is simply put to sleep, and the OS' thread scheduling picks up from there. The calling thread can still dispatch incoming message sent messages.

Comment: @IInspectable The calling thread is put on hold/blocked until the window's window procedure has finished handling the message (the window procedure is executed in the context of the thread which owns/created the window). From MSDN: "If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure." "The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message.". But, just as you said: However, the sending thread will process incoming nonqueued messages while waiting for its message to be processed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: None of the answers indicates, that message processing is serialized. There are several scenarios where a window procedure can be re-entered, while a message is being handled. The assumption that messages will be processed one at a time is ill-fated. And wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable Well for my use case I am concerned mainly with updates happening to the Windows clipboard.  Is there any chance that these updates could end up being processed out of order or in parallel?  I should have narrowed down my use case to avoid confusion.

Comment: @IInspectable "There are several scenarios where a window procedure can be re-entered, while a message is being handled." That is a good point and should be kept in mind.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: [WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649024.aspx): *"Sent to the clipboard owner when a call to the [EmptyClipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649037.aspx) function empties the clipboard."* In other words, reentrancy can be an issue with the clipboard as well.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't mean to turn this into a discussion fest, but my real concern was that windows messages could be processed out of order, i.e. a recent message would be processed before an older one.  This appears to not be possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: This **is** the case. Low priority messages (like `WM_PAINT` or `WM_MOUSEMOVE`) get processed only after all higher priority message have been processed. So yes, newer messages are (regularly) processed, before older ones. It's becoming increasingly unclear, what you are really after. You may want to revisit your question and ask your real question.

Comment: I was trying to generalize a narrow use case which cannot be done apparently.  I will repost a new question and ping you when it is up.

Answer (score 1):

Window messages are sometimes stored on the message queue, and sometimes they are not. Examples of window messages not stored on the queue are WM_ACTIVATE, WM_SETFOCUS and WM_SETCURSOR. Other messages, like WM_PAINT, are placed on the message queue.

A window's window procedure is never called in parellel (see previous answer).

The messages are indeed handled in a sequence and GetMessage pulls the first message from the queue. One important thing to note however is that messages can "disappear" from the queue without being processed. For example, windows internally maintains a structure (PAINTSTRUCT) for each window in which it keeps track of the window's invalid region. As soon as any part of the window's client area is invalidated windows places a WM_PAINT message on the message queue. However, if the invalid region is validated (with for example a call to ValidateRect) Windows actually removes the message from the queue. Also, if another region was added to the invalid region Windows does not place another WM_PAINT message on the queue, it updates the already placed WM_PAINT message with the updated region.